# How can I get Backbone data from nested JSON key?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I use `Backbone.js` library, but my server return  data in format:

```
{
     "status":"OK",
     "message":"",
     "data":{"table":{"id":"4","name":"\u0421\u0442\u043e\u043b 1","tableType":"0","chairNumber":"0","posX":"0","posY":"0","width":"0","height":"0","angle":"0","plan":"0"}}
}
```

Backbone expected only data:

```
{"table":{"id":"4","name":"\u0421\u0442\u043e\u043b 1","tableType":"0","chairNumber":"0","posX":"0","posY":"0","width":"0","height":"0","angle":"0","plan":"0"}}
```

How can I use nested level `data` for backbone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parse: function (response, options) {
    return response.data;
}
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse